# Connection-link selection not accurate using javascript library draw2d

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, connection, selection, draw2d

I want to implement a graph designer using draw2d library. In demo, the click on any connection-link is accurate, otherwise in my application the click on the links is not accurate because most of the times the connection is not selected (the elements such as a VectorFigure don't have selection problems). The only difference between my application and demo is the container of the div called "paintarea"; in fact, I don't use a frame dedicated so the paintarea doesn't start form x=0 and y=0.
Anyone can help me? Is very important...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you use a scroll container/div?

Sometimes the users enclose the paintarea in another scrollable DIV.
In this case you should use the [setViewPort](http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/resources/jsdoc/draw2d/Canvas.html#setViewPort) ...or inspect the [Viewport](http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/resources/demo/demo/970_viewport/index.html) Demo.

Comment: perfect...it seems to work!! THANK YOU A LOT and compliment for the framework :)

Comment: I must reopen question! If I use "setViewPort" I can select element and connection correctly but until I scroll!! If I scroll, elements are yet selectable but connection are not selectable!! what could be the problem? thanks in advance

Comment: If I select a connection without scroll and then scroll downward without move mouse, it select the connection selected before...I did some tests and I saw that the selection of connections is "translated" as the scrolling!!

Comment: EDIT: another information: my workflow scroll container does not start from top:0px and left:0px of the page, but is contained by another div

Comment: Did you you have a cascade DIV's container hirach.

Comment: excuse me but in the code there was an error because after the "setViewPort" was setting the workflow.scrollArea also...without it, it works good!